# Scala - List.map type infer error fail

Tags: scala, types

this code compile error

```
val kk2: List[(Int, Double)] = (1, 0.5) :: (2, 0.6)
kk2.map((n1, d1) => n1) // compile error
```

i want List[Int, Double] => List[Int]
how can i solve this error ?

Comment: You didn't say what the is exactly. If it's just the inference error, add an annotation.

Comment: use. tup => tup._1

Comment: Is that the error? That doesn't look like an error, or at least not all of it.

Comment: You get an error from the first line, before you even get to the map, so the subject line's a bit misleading

Comment: @kimyongin did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

First, to construct a `List[(Int, Double)]` using a cons operator `::`, you need to append an element of such list (e.g. in your case `(1, 0.5)`) to an *already existing* list, not to another element. In other words, on the right hand side of `::` there must be a list of tuple(s), not just one tuple, so wrap your `(2, 0.6)` tuple in a `List`. Be careful: `List(2, 0.6)` would give you a list of two elements, 2 and 0.6, but you want a list of one tuple element, so you need two pairs of parenthesis: `List((2, 0.6))`. As correctly pointed out in a comment, you can also do it in a cleaner way as `(1, 0.5) :: (2, 0.6) :: Nil`, which is a recursive way of defining a list by using only the cons operator (Nil is an empty list).

Second, when you map over a tuple, you must use a partial function for the pattern matching mechanism to kick in, or simply put, you need the `case`.

So:

```
val kk2: List[(Int, Double)] = (1, 0.5) :: (2, 0.6) :: Nil
kk2.map { case (n1, d1) => n1 } // List(1,2)
```

Comment: `(1, 0.5) ::(2, 0.6)::Nil` would be more idiomatic

Comment: Change the bit after "So:" then? :)